# How can this be simplified without using optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not using an ES version that allows for optional chaining.  Maybe something along the lines of using indexOf()?...

```
[key]:key.includes("thing1") || key.includes("thing2")
                    ? Number(e.target.value)
                    : e.target.value
```

Comment: Optional chaining cannot even be applied here, even if supported...

Comment: The above code example does not use any optional chaining. What is presented is a [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) where the condition uses a [Logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

Comment: `/thing1|thing2/.test(key) ? ... : ...`

Comment: `['thing1', 'thing2'].includes(key)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that checks if `key` is equal to one of these, not if either of these is a substring of `key`

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It's not overcomplicated, and it's perfectly clear. (And is `key` an array, or a string? Both have `includes` and `indexOf` methods.)